# How do i programmatically access an interface created in GUI builder?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a webapp that has a GUI, and I need to launch said GUI at startup **AND** programmatically access the content of a text area and two text boxes from a handler, this is **NOT** a strong need and I am OK with waiting a little while to get an answer.

Comment: Can you post some code and give an example. In general, you'll be required to access content of text boxes in some sort of handler which you can access by using e.parameter.[widget's name] in the handler function.

Comment: You may have to keep updating your question with details over time,a s you refine your sense of the need and problem.  Eventually more people will see it, and you'll get an answer, or you'll find your own answer and then you can submit that (if no one else has answered already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Gui (assuming you have did using GUI builder) in start-up using,

```
 function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("MyGui"));
  return app;
}
```

You can set the id's and name's of widgets in the GUI builder, then use them in the code using,

```
app.getElementById('id') or e.parameter.[name]
```

You can also refer to the following URLs for gui's

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/gui_builder
2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp
3. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service